# Script Batch para apagar arquivo de acordo com um tempo definido

Tags: batch

Estou precisando de um batch que apague arquivos específicos de uma pasta de backup depois que os arquivos completarem 30 dias (exemplo).

Encontrei este código mas ele usa um programa externo:

```
@echo off
move c:\TESTE\*.* d:\TESTE2\
exit
```

Se precisar criar os diretórios antes vá inserindo os comandos mkdir nome_do_diretorio

Para apagar arquivos antigos eu usei este aqui:

```
@echo off

REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
REM // Define as variaveis de data //
REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Rem make var nowDay
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=/" %%A IN ('date/t') DO SET nowDay=%%A

REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
REM // Lista em log os arquivos encontrados //
REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

FORFILES /S /p C:\teste1\ /d -3 /C "CMD /C echo @FILE @FDATE" > C:\Logs\%nowDay%.log

REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
REM // Remove os arquivos encontrados //
REM ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

FORFILES /S /p C:\teste1\ /d -3 /c "CMD /C DEL @FILE /Q"

exit
```

Existe uma maneira mais simples?

Comment: Eu aceito sim, pode me mandar sua dica.

Comment: A forma mais utilizada para resolver esse problema realmente é com `forfiles`, mas tem algumas opções interessantes nessa resposta no SOen [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Answer (score -1):

Existe mais de um jeito de fazer isso.
Criando um batch na pasta Inicializar do Menu Iniciar seria um deles.
Toda a vez que o Windows iniciar irá rodar esse script...

---

Para filtrar você pode usar o `FORFILES` descrito na pergunta - muito mais cômodo.

- Ou realizar um `FOR`:

```
> FOR %f in (*) do @ECHO %~tf %f
29/12/2018 18:31 VID_20181229_193116.mp4
29/12/2018 15:33 VID_20181229_163310.mp4
29/12/2018 17:40 VID_20181229_184027.mp4
29/12/2018 18:07 VID_20181229_190741.mp4
```

Esse script obtém data e nome do arquivo, mas carrega também hora.

- Neste caso poderia combinar com um `DIR`:

```
> FOR /f "usebackq skip=7 tokens=1,4*" %s in (`dir /a-`) do @ECHO %s %t
29/12/2018 VID_20181229_193116.mp4
29/12/2018 VID_20181229_163310.mp4
29/12/2018 VID_20181229_184027.mp4
29/12/2018 VID_20181229_190741.mp4
```

De qualquer forma, em ambos teria que rodar outro FOR para tratar as datas.

---

No entanto, a maneira que considero mais adequada é pelo próprio recurso de

- **Agendamento de Tarefas do Windows:**

```
> SCHTASKS /create /tn deletarBackupsMensais /tr "CMD /c delete *.bkp"  /sc MONTHLY
```

Esse comando cria uma tarefa agendada que vai se repetir a cada mês independente de você executar ou reiniciar o computador. <sub>Considere editar o parâmetro de arquivos a serem afetados.</sub>

Para remover a tarefa agendada basta executar:

```
> SCHTASKS /delete /tn deletarBackupsMensais /f
```